# Camunda Rest API Assign Task Group

Tags: bpmn, camunda

We are using Camunda in our application for approval flow. As per the below documentation from Camunda we can create the task and assign it to user.

I wanted to know if we can assign the task to a group instead of individual user

Request parameters - I tried with `"candidateGroups" : {"value"}` but no luck.

```
{
  "id": "aTaskId",
  "name": "My Task",
  "description": "This have to be done very urgent",
  "priority" : 30,
  "assignee" : "peter",
  "owner" : "mary",
  "delegationState" : "PENDING",
  "due" : "2014-08-30T10:00:00",
  "followUp" : "2014-08-25T10:00:00",
  "parentTaskId" : "aParentTaskId",
  "caseInstanceId" : "aCaseInstanceId" 
}
```

Comment: Is it a add-hoc task without BPMN process?

Comment: @jklee Yes right

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a task to a group. But you can define candidate groups into your BPMN process. This can also be a service/query.

> The candidateGroups attribute: this custom extension allows you to
>   make a group a candidate for a task.

```
<userTask id="theTask" name="my task" camunda:candidateGroups="management, accountancy" />
```

> This is exactly
>   the same as using a potentialOwner construct as defined above. Note
>   that it is not required to use the group(management) declaration as is
>   the case with the potential owner construct, since this attribute can
>   only be used for groups.

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/bpmn20/tasks/user-task/#candidate-groups